# ios swift convert string date to new format

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert this string date "Wed, 25 Jan 2017 08:00:00 GMT" to another format but `DateFormatter`return nil

my code so far :

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        print(dateFormatter.date(from: "Wed, 25 Jan 2017 08:00:00 GMT")!)
```

any suggestions

Comment: For that you need to set dateFormat to `E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z`

Comment: Can you please tell in which format you want date after that

Comment: then i need to return a string date with this format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: So first set dateFormat to `E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z` get date from it then set dateFormat to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and get string from it.

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dateFormat is wrong :

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
if let date = formatter.date(from: "Wed, 25 Jan 2017 08:00:00 GMT") {
    print("Date : \(date)")
}
```

**Output** :
`Date : 2017-01-25 08:00:00 +0000`